# Spring Roo Gvnix. Json response on mvc controller request with form data parameters

Tags: json, spring-roo, gvnix

I need to generate a Json response for a POST made with parameters in form data, not in Json.

Example:
  My request:

> curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:
>   multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
>   -F "firstName=Manolete" -F "lastName=Manolón" -F "address=villa arriba" -F "city=meryville" -F "telephone=666666666" -F
>   "homepage=alguna.homepage.es" -F "email=alguno@hotmail.com" -F
>   "birthday=1314595427866" "http://localhost:8080/PetClinicRoo/owners"

Current request:

> curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{firstName: "Manolete",
>   lastName:"Manolón",  address:"villa arriba", city: "Meryville",
>   telephone:"66666666", homepage:"alguna.homepage.es",
>   email:"alguno@hotmail.com", birthDay: 1314596527943, }'
>   "http://localhost:8080/PetClinicRoo/owners"

I could handwrite the code but this implies getting out of spring roo management all the application web tier, and further modifications wouldn't be automatically made.

Answer (score 0):

You can push-in the controller method and you modify it as needed, Spring Roo management will work.

Comment: Unfortunately we have a lot of entities in our aplication. Pushing in all of the post methods its a huge work. Also, further modifications on our entities wuldn't be automatically managed by Spring Roo

Comment: Another option is to handwrite the needed code directly in your .java files, if the method exists in the .aj file, Roo will remove the code in the .aj file.

Answer (score 0):

We have several options:

1.- Use spring roo and then pushing in the methods

- Generate all the web tier using spring roo
- Pushing-in all the post methods
- Modify the response

Inconvenients: once you push-in the methods, spring roo doesn’t manage them, so further modifications woldn’t be made automatically

2.-Handwrite the web tier.

- Use spring ro to generate entities
- Handwrite the web layer

Inconvenients: implies more work than the previous option.

3.- Extend Spring Roo in order to generate the method automatically.

I think this is our best option because he have a lot of entities.

Comment: I agree that the 3º option is the best, but instead _modify_ Spring Roo you should _extend_ it by creating an add-on (your own Roo annotation) which generate whatever you need in your controller. Look at ``addon create advanced`` command. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help! You are right, extending is better. I will edit the response.